# Is it possible to dump the cookes in the request headers using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, python-requests

My goal is to get the cookies from the request headers using the request headers.

I have tried using request, selenium and seleniumwire, but the results that I got from them are not the same as the ones I found in the browser(chrome).

Code I tried:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
import pickle, time

print("Start\n")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('window-size=414x736')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
options.add_argument('blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--enable-file-cookies')

##  Get the URL
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver', options=options)
browser.get("https://www.xxxxxxx.com/xxxxxx")

time.sleep(5)

print(browser.get_cookies())

browser.quit()
```

I also tried using the requests library in python, but the result is the same as the selenium.

The headers request I found in the browser tool which I want to get from selenium:
[image]

Comment: What is the result produced by the code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

For getting the cookies,

```
browser.get("https://www.example.com")
# get all the cookies from this domain
cookies = browser.get_cookies()
# store it somewhere, maybe a text file
```

For restoring the cookies

```
browser.get("https://www.example.com")
# get back the cookies
cookies = {‘name’ : ‘foo’, ‘value’ : ‘bar’}
browser.add_cookies(cookies)
```